# code throwing error user-defined not defined

Tags: vba, ms-word

code is below, Thanks all,
this function will create a word document

I updated the post, this was working good with 32-bit office, we upgraded to o365 64-bit and throwing error

Any suggestions would be great

```
Function ShipMerge_JMail(invNum As Long)

On Error GoTo ShipMergeErr
'Stop
Dim objWord As New Word.Application
'objWord.Visible = True
Dim objWordDoc As Word.Document
Set objWordDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(ShipMergeDot)
Dim temp1, temp, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim DetailCount As Integer
Dim rstShipDetails As DAO.Recordset, rstFactory As DAO.Recordset, dbs As DAO.Database
Dim CellNames(5) As String, CellTest As Variant, PartTotal As Long
Dim SQL1 As String
Dim GTotal As Double    'Changed system to use sug retail as price

CellNames(1) = "[QTY]"
CellNames(2) = "[DESC]"
CellNames(3) = "[PN]"
CellNames(4) = "[Cost]"
CellNames(5) = "[comments]"

'CellNames(1) = "[QTY]"
'CellNames(2) = "[DESC]"
'CellNames(3) = "[PN]"
'CellNames(4) = "[QTY]"
'CellNames(5) = "[comments]"

SQL1 = ""
SQL1 = SQL1 + "SELECT DISTINCTROW tblShipingInfo.[To Field], "
SQL1 = SQL1 + "tblShipingInfo.From, tblShipingInfo.[Shipped VIA], tblShipingInfo.[QAH No], "
SQL1 = SQL1 + "tblShipingInfo.[Ship Date], tblShipingInfo.[report no] AS [QID #], "
SQL1 = SQL1 + "tblShipingInfo.[Invoice  #], tblShipingInfo.[Atten], "
SQL1 = SQL1 + "tblShipping_Details.[Control Invoice  #] AS [CI#], "
SQL1 = SQL1 + "tblShipping_Details.Qty, tblShipping_Details.Desc,tblShipping_Details.PN, "
SQL1 = SQL1 + "tblShipingInfo.[Fax Date],tblShipping_Details.cost , tblShipping_Details.Comments "
SQL1 = SQL1 + "FROM tblShipingInfo LEFT JOIN tblShipping_Details ON "
SQL1 = SQL1 + "tblShipingInfo.[Invoice  #] = tblShipping_Details.[Control Invoice  #]"
'SQL1 = SQL1 + ""
'SQL1 = SQL1 + ""
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rstFactory = dbs.OpenRecordset("qryFactories", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rstShipDetails = dbs.OpenRecordset(SQL1)

'change to docx 6 mar 2015
objWordDoc.SaveAs Filename:="c:\temp\shipinv.docx"

'objWordDoc.PrintOut Background:=True
objWord.Options.BackgroundSave = True

While objWord.BackgroundSavingStatus > 0
   ' Wait for Word to finish Saving
   DoEvents
Wend
'While objWord.BackgroundPrintingStatus > 0
   ' Wait for Word to finish printing.. can use the backgroundsave status later....
'   DoEvents
'Wend
DoEvents
'rstShipDetails.Filter = "[Invoice  #]= 671"
'rstShipDetails.Filter = "[Invoice  #]= 1072"
rstShipDetails.Filter = "[Invoice  #]= " & invNum
rstShipDetails.MoveFirst
Set rstShipDetails = rstShipDetails.OpenRecordset
DetailCount = rstShipDetails.RecordCount
If DetailCount = 0 Then GoTo NoRecords
rstShipDetails.MoveLast
DetailCount = rstShipDetails.RecordCount
rstShipDetails.MoveFirst

rstFactory.Filter = "[Factory ID]= '" & rstShipDetails![To Field] & "'"
Set rstFactory = rstFactory.OpenRecordset
rstFactory.MoveLast
Dim mAtten As String
mAtten = Space(1)
'if no info in the table for attention field use the default factory to info
mAtten = IIf(IsNull(rstShipDetails![Atten]), rstFactory![Atten], rstShipDetails![Atten])


Dim newrow As Word.Row


'SELECT DISTINCTROW tblShipingInfo.[To Field], tblShipingInfo.From, tblShipingInfo.[Shipped VIA], tblShipingInfo.[Ship Date], tblShipingInfo.[report no] AS [QID #], tblShipingInfo.[Invoice  #], tblShipping_Details.[Control Invoice  #] AS [CI#], tblShipping_Details.Qty, tblShipping_Details.Desc, tblShipping_Details.PN, tblShipingInfo.[Fax Date], tblShipping_Details.Comments
```

'FROM tblShipingInfo LEFT JOIN tblShipping_Details ON tblShipingInfo.[Invoice  #] = tblShipping_Details.[Control Invoice  #];

```
If DetailCount > 1 Then
    For i = 1 To DetailCount - 1
        Set newrow = objWordDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Add(BeforeRow:=objWordDoc.Tables(1).Rows(2))
    Next
End If
For i = 1 To DetailCount
'Fill out the table

    With objWordDoc.Tables(1).Rows(i + 1)
    Dim c
    j = 1
        'For Each c In .Cells
        '    CellTest = rstShipDetails(CellNames(j))
        '    Select Case j
        '        Case 1  ' qty
        '            PartTotal = PartTotal + Val(CellTest)
        '        Case 4  'total price
        '            CellTest = "$" & CellTest & ".00"
        '    End Select
        '    If Not IsNull(CellTest) Then
        '        c.Range.InsertAfter Nz(CellTest, "")
        '    End If
        '
        '    j = j + 1
        'Next c
        For Each c In .Cells    'new cost system
            CellTest = rstShipDetails(CellNames(j))
            Select Case j
                Case 1  ' qty
                    PartTotal = Val(CellTest)
                Case 4  'total price
                    CellTest = "$" & Round(((CellTest * PartTotal) * 0.5), 2)
                    GTotal = GTotal + CellTest  'collect the total price of parts
            End Select
            If Not IsNull(CellTest) Then  'put the value in the table
                c.Range.InsertAfter Nz(CellTest, "")
            End If
                
            j = j + 1
        Next c
    End With
   
    rstShipDetails.MoveNext
Next
Dim location

rstShipDetails.MoveFirst
objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="GrandTotal"
objWord.Selection.InsertAfter "$" & GTotal

'objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Atten"
'objWord.Selection.InsertAfter mAtten
'objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="CompanyName"
'objWord.Selection.InsertAfter rstFactory![Compay Name]
'objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="FactoryCity"
'objWord.Selection.InsertAfter rstFactory![City]
'objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="FactoryCountryZip"
'objWord.Selection.InsertAfter rstFactory![Country] & ", " & rstFactory![zip]
'objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="FactoryID"
'objWord.Selection.InsertAfter rstShipDetails![To Field]
'objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="FactoryName"
'objWord.Selection.InsertAfter rstFactory![Factory Name]
'objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="FactoryProvidence"
'objWord.Selection.InsertAfter rstFactory![Providence]
'objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="FactoryStreet"
'objWord.Selection.InsertAfter rstFactory![Street]
objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="InvNum"
objWord.Selection.InsertAfter Format(rstShipDetails![Invoice  #], "00000")
objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="ShipDate"
objWord.Selection.InsertAfter Nz(rstShipDetails![Ship Date], "")

'use text box instead of bookmarks 6 mar 2015
Dim mADD As String
mADD = ""
mADD = mADD & rstFactory![Compay Name] & vbNewLine
mADD = mADD & rstShipDetails![To Field] & vbNewLine
mADD = mADD & rstFactory![Street] & vbNewLine
mADD = mADD & rstFactory![City] & vbNewLine
mADD = mADD & rstFactory![Providence] & vbNewLine
mADD = mADD & rstFactory![Country] & ", " & rstFactory![zip] & vbNewLine
mADD = mADD & rstFactory![Compay Name] & vbNewLine


objWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes("Rectangle 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = mADD

'objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="QIDNum"
'objWord.Selection.InsertAfter Nz(rstShipDetails![QID #], "None")
Dim QAHNo As Variant
'QAHNo = DLookup("[QAH #]", "qid report", "[Report Number:]= '" & rstShipDetails![QID #] & "'")
QAHNo = Nz(rstShipDetails![QAH No], "None")
'objWord.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="QAHNo"
'objWord.Selection.InsertAfter QAHNo
objWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 9").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "QAH/QIS/QIC No.: " & vbNewLine & QAHNo
objWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 10").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Attention: " & mAtten


objWordDoc.Save
objWordDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges

DoCmd.Hourglass True

Set rstShipDetails = Nothing
Set rstFactory = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing


objWord.Quit
Set objWordDoc = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing

DoCmd.Hourglass False
```

Comment: You have likely not added a required reference to your VBA project.

Comment: Thats not whole code

Comment: Sorry updated the code, this all started after upgrading to 64-bit

Comment: As BigBen already asked, which line raises the error?

Comment: its showing error on function, first line

Comment: You mean the line "On Error GoTo ShipMergeErr"? That label is missing.

Comment: any suggestions?